# Calling SQL Procedure from C# / ASp.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I have been working on a website for an employer which contains database information, allowing for the user to edit the information at will. A request that I have received is to add a button called Deactivate which onclick should add the tag 'X' to a column named 'Inactive' stating that the row is in fact inactive to any rows with a checkbox ticked. The checkboxes have already been added to the GridView.

I have tried adding stored procedures through SQL Server Management Studio however following the tutorials listed in the Microsoft Documents, I do not have the option to add / create new stored procedure when I right click the stored procedures folder.

I have been searching the internet for days and I don't know whether I am not finding the correct answers or whether I simply do not understand them properly.

**SQL Deactivate Command Pseudocode**

```
UPDATE Products SET Inactive="X" WHERE chkBox="True"
```

**HTML**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Customer_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" InsertVisible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierID" HeaderText="SupplierID" SortExpression="SupplierID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityPerUnit" HeaderText="QuantityPerUnit" SortExpression="QuantityPerUnit" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsInStock" HeaderText="UnitsInStock" SortExpression="UnitsInStock" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsOnOrder" HeaderText="UnitsOnOrder" SortExpression="UnitsOnOrder" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReorderLevel" HeaderText="ReorderLevel" SortExpression="ReorderLevel" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued" SortExpression="Discontinued" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Inactive" HeaderText="Inactive" SortExpression="Inactive" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand=
        "DELETE FROM [Products] WHERE [ProductID] = @ProductID"
        InsertCommand=
        "INSERT INTO [Products] ([ProductName], [SupplierID], [CategoryID], [QuantityPerUnit], [UnitPrice], [UnitsInStock], [UnitsOnOrder], [ReorderLevel], [Discontinued], [Inactive]) VALUES (@ProductName, @SupplierID, @CategoryID, @QuantityPerUnit, @UnitPrice, @UnitsInStock, @UnitsOnOrder, @ReorderLevel, @Discontinued, @Inactive)"
        SelectCommand=
        "SELECT * FROM [Products]"
        UpdateCommand=
        "UPDATE [Products] SET [ProductName] = @ProductName, [SupplierID] = @SupplierID, [CategoryID] = @CategoryID, [QuantityPerUnit] = @QuantityPerUnit, [UnitPrice] = @UnitPrice, [UnitsInStock] = @UnitsInStock, [UnitsOnOrder] = @UnitsOnOrder, [ReorderLevel] = @ReorderLevel, [Discontinued] = @Discontinued, [Inactive] = @Inactive WHERE [ProductID] = @ProductID">
        <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SupplierID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="QuantityPerUnit" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UnitPrice" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UnitsInStock" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UnitsOnOrder" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ReorderLevel" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Discontinued" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Inactive" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SupplierID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="QuantityPerUnit" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UnitPrice" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UnitsInStock" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UnitsOnOrder" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ReorderLevel" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Discontinued" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Inactive" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:Button ID="ASPda" runat="Server" Text="Deactivate ASP" OnClick="Deactivate"/>
        </form>

    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Specific button I want to run the Deactivate command.

```
<asp:Button ID="ASPda" runat="Server" Text="Deactivate ASP" OnClick="Deactivate"/>
```

Comment: what do you mean.. you want how to create stored procedure?

Comment: Well, I'm only really asking for help with running SQL code from within my website, however if I do need to fix this issue with creating a stored procedure then any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confused with your frontend code and SQL code.

Your SQL pseudo code should be something like:

`UPDATE Products SET Active = 0 WHERE ProductID = @ProductID`

The SQL query above will set the `Active` column to 0 where the `ProductID` matches the one you pass from your application (of course just adjust it to the actual column names and values).

Then on your `GridView` `TemplateField` `ItemTemplate`, add this markup:

`<asp:HiddenField ID="hfProdID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>' />`

Then on your button click event,

```
    foreach (GridViewRow rw in GridView.Rows) //Loop through all the rows in the GridView
    {
        if(rw.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) //Checks if current row in the loop is a valid DataRow, not a Header or Footer row (which doesn't include the CheckBox and the data)
        {
            CheckBox cbProd = (CheckBox)rw.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow"); //Finds the checkbox in the first column

            HiddenField hfProd = (HiddenField)rw.Cells[0].FindControl("hfProdID"); //Finds the HiddenField in the first column where ProductID is stored
            if(cbProd.Checked == true)  //Checks if the current checkbox is selected, if yes, execute the UPDATE query by passing the Product ID as the parameter.
            {
                string sqlConnStr = ("put actual connection string here");
                string sqlCmdStr = ("UPDATE Products SET Active = 0 WHERE ProductID = @ProductID"); //UPDATE query
                using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnStr))
                {
                    using(SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmdStr, sqlConn))
                    {
                        sqlConn.Open();
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductID", hfProd.Value); //Product ID saved in HiddenField
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlConn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you can tell I am fairly new to C# and SQL so I apologise if I am frustrating. Where you said _Then on your button click event,_ , how exactly do I add that in. Do I add a procedure / function in C# or do I add it into the ASP.NET?

Comment: From the design view, you need to double click your button, and it will redirect you to code behind, there will be created a `ASPda_Click` event. You need to copy paste and adjust the code I provided to your need.

Comment: I ran your code after editing it to my needs. Now I am getting a lot of errors stating _; expected_ and _} expected._ Also the HiddenField markup you gave me returns this error: _System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'. 'asp:HiddenField' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField'._

Comment: Oh, my bad, I thought it was vb.net. I'll convert it to c#.

Comment: You state that I have to insert the name of my stored procedure, however, in the question I asked, I cannot create stored procedures for some reason, there is just no option to do so in SQL Server Management Studio. There is just simply no option on the menu when I right click on the stored procedures folder in the object explorer.

Comment: I updated the code. Adjust the column name and values to your need.

Comment: Okay, everything works well now, except one error I am receiving, which is the one I mentioned earlier which is the one containing 3 lines of System.Web.UI.WebControls

Comment: Changed it to: `<asp:HiddenField ID="hfProdID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ProductID"%>)' />`, but it's still giving me the same error. It also gives the warning: `Element 'HiddenField' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.`

Comment: It should be inside `<ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>`

Comment: Ahh, okay, just a bit of miscommunication there for a sec, so is that all that I should need to do what I need to do, because when I click the button after selecting one of the checkboxes and only after selecting one of the checkboxes, it crashes with this error code: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.'
`

Comment: Check the updated code. Forgot to add open and close.

Comment: Returns Error: `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '<%#Eval(\"ProductID\"%>)' to data type int.` Regardless of whether I enter an alphabetical or numerical input

Comment: Can you check why it returns as having backslashes \?

Comment: Just realised, there is a difference between the actual error that it gives me and the one that it shows in error details. `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '<%#Eval("ProductID"%>)' to data type int.'` is the one that is given to me before going into view details.

Comment: Check the markup again, it should be '<%#Eval("ProductID")%>' You misplaced the )

Comment: Okay, this is new, it changed the entire column of Inactive to 1

Comment: ooh, okay, it works now :) Only one problem, the change is only visible whenever I restart debugging.

Comment: You need to rebind the `GridView` (calling the databind method to fetch the updated records from the database again). Also see my EDIT on the code, I've put a condition `if(rw.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)` to only apply the code on the actual rows with `CheckBox` and not include Header and Footer Rows.

Comment: How exactly do I rebind the gridview to do that?

Comment: Same way how you shown the data on your `GridView` upon loading of your application

Comment: Aha, working perfectly dude, thanks for the help, seriously, you are **AMAZING!!!**

Comment: Glad it helped. Though you should read more tutorials so we can avoid long discussions like this (which isn't really recommended here in SO).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 public static DataTable GetData()
        {
            String callProcedure = "exec my_proc";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string here!"))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = callProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        adp.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do I added in place of the connection string based on this: `ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnectionString %>"`?

Comment: is that connection string from app.config?

Comment: I don't have any app.config file but the connection string there was automatically generated by Visual Studio and has worked connecting to the database so far. It is taken directly from the ASP.NET code

Comment: try to assign your connection to a string str = 'your connection string here' then Debug and check str if it is the right string value of your connection. Then place it in new SqlConnection(str).